# Sorting numbers with JPanel

Tags: java, sorting

So, this code is supposed take 5 integers form the text fields written by the user and sort the integers written in the text field in ascending order.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;

public class PushCounterPanelSorter extends JPanel
{
    private JButton sort;
    private JLabel label;
    private JTextField textfield, textfield2, textfield3, textfield4, textfield5;

    public PushCounterPanelSorter()
    {
        textfield = new JTextField(10);
            textfield.setBounds(50, 100, 200, 30);
        textfield2 = new JTextField(10);
            textfield2.setBounds(50, 150, 200, 30);
        textfield3 = new JTextField(10);
            textfield3.setBounds(50, 200, 200, 30);
        textfield4 = new JTextField(10);
            textfield4.setBounds(50, 150, 200, 30);
        textfield5 = new JTextField(10);
            textfield5.setBounds(50, 150, 200, 30);
        sort = new JButton("Sort");
        label = new JLabel();
        sort.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
        add(sort);
        add(label);
        add(textfield);
        add(textfield2);
        add(textfield3);
        add(textfield4);
        add(textfield5);
        setBackground(Color.cyan);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 40));
        
    }

    private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
        {
            int[] numsort = new int[] {};
            int num1 = Integer.parseInt(textfield.getText());
            int num2 = Integer.parseInt(textfield2.getText());
            int num3 = Integer.parseInt(textfield3.getText());
            int num4 = Integer.parseInt(textfield4.getText());
            int num5 = Integer.parseInt(textfield5.getText());
            numsort[0] = num1;
            numsort[1] = num2;
            numsort[2] = num3;
            numsort[3] = num4;
            numsort[4] = num5;
            
            Arrays.sort(numsort);
            
            for(int i = 0; i<numsort.length-2; i++) {
                System.out.print(numsort[i]);
            }
            label.setText("Sorted: " + numsort);
        }
    }
}
```

It throws index out bounds exception, but I am pretty sure there is more than that. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You're initializing the array as having 0 items: `int[] numsort = new int[] {};`. Instead, declare it to have the number of items needed: `int[] numsort = new int[5];`

Comment: Note that the problem has nothing to do with JPanels and all to do with declaring and initializing array variables. Also note that you can have JTextField arrays. Later, we must talk about using `.setBounds(...)` and why it should be avoided.